# How can you automatically trim a new layer in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I know there are short cuts (Alt + ] or [) when creating a new layer in after effects that will trim the layer to either side of the Current Time Indicator.

The question is, is there a better way to create a new layer and not have to manually trim it because by default it spans the entire comp. For example, can you create a new shape layer and trim it to the current Work Area? I am specifically looking for the most efficient method for trimming new layers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What to you mean "set to the current workspace"? A workspace is your window setup and has nothing to do with your project.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect term, you are correct. I was referring to the "Work Area" and have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to automatically trim layers as you import them.  You can trim a comp to your work area, if you've selected a beginning and end point on your timeline (using B and N), but this isn't really going to help you.